# What type of different encryption techniques are used by contemporary armies

Tags: encryption

Please guide me. if there is any paper, research or presentation kindly share

Answer (score 2):

The internals of contemporary military forces are largely kept secret, but many do release standards for use with various security levels in government and military operations.

For the US, you're going to want to check out [NIST's cryptography branch](https://www.nist.gov/topics/cryptography), particularly the Cryptographic Standards Program (CSP). They offer various standards for which cryptosystems and algorithms are acceptable for use in various circumstances (e.g. for various secrecy levels and purposes). These govern various types of cryptography, including symmetric, asymmetric, and elliptic-curve for general use, guidelines for full-disk encryption, secure erasure, and various other security requirements and guidelines. To a lesser extent, government organisations will be held to the [FIPS 140-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIPS_140-2) standard for information processing.

For the UK, you're mostly looking for standards from the [NCSC](https://www.ncsc.gov.uk/topics/cryptography), which is the public branch of GCHQ. Their remit is much wider than that of NIST, including providing general security advice for British organisations in both the public and private sectors, and advice to individuals at home.

Japan has [CRYPTREC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRYPTREC), which the EU used as a baseline for their [NESSIE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NESSIE) project in the early 2000s, although no single cryptographic standard was produced as a result.

Germany's [BSI](https://www.bsi.bund.de/EN/Home/home_node.html) (*Bundesamt für Sicherheit in der Informationstechnik*, not to be confused with the British Standards Institute) does a similar job to the UK's NCSC and has some publications that standardise the use of cryptography in German government and military.

Most of these standards focus upon cryptography on computing platforms, however there are other standards for things like secure voice (e.g. [MELP/MELPe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed-excitation_linear_prediction), [SCIP 230](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Communications_Interoperability_Protocol), and [ANDVT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANDVT)) which do not fit within the regular cryptographic standards papers but still involve cryptography.

There are probably hundreds more standards for the use of cryptography in different nations across the globe. Some are public, some are classified. Enumerating them all would be a serious challenge!